# Power BI - Extract / Moving value to a separate column

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, data-extraction, kpi, csv

I have a column that includes 2 different values for more than 100k customers

The values are: "**Consumer**" , "**SMB**"

How can I move "SMB" values to a separate column ? I want each value to be shown in a different column so I can use KPI for each one of the values.

For ex: I want to create 2 different KPIs, one for SMB and 1 for Consumer, which show how money in total each segment has been charged.

Answer (score 2):

When you load the data in the Power Query editor, use the command to split the column with the values. Use the comma as the delimiter.

[image]